# Heroku Error 404, "ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/client/build/index.html'"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, create-react-app

I am trying to deploy MERN website in heroku but getting following error:

`"ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/client/build/index.html'"`

I have ran the project locally, and everything is working fine.
I have added the following in **package.json**:

`"heoku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"`

also here is the code in my **server.js**

```
// Deployment
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client/build")));
  app.get("*", (req, res) =>
    // res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client", "public", "index.html"))
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client/build/index.html"))
  );
} else {
  app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("API IS RUNNING.");
  });
}
```

It should create react `build` folder by running `npm run build` but I think `heroku-postbuild`command is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misspelled `heroku` to `heoku` so the actual command in package.json should be:

`"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"`